# Is it possible to update, upgrade and administer Ubuntu via the GUI and never touch a command line?

Tags: updates, gui, automation, administration, administrator

Hi I use Debian and Fedora and have since 2007.

It seems that Ubuntu has marketed and built itself to make Linux easier and more user friendly for daily use.

**PROBLEM:**

I am planning to use Linux in my company that I'm starting in two years but I need a Linux that, like Windows, is fully GUI and doesn't need using the shell for any purpose.

For example this guide:https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-from-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-to-ubuntu-18-04. Even when you use the GUI, you still have to type commands in the terminal.

**QUESTION:**

Is Ubuntu like this? Can I give a Ubuntu computer to a employee who would rather die, than to have to touch a command line/`shell`, ever?

Comment: As far as possible, please use code tags for code.

Comment: By upgrade do you mean update patches and fixes, like Windows update? If you mean upgrade between OS versions, it's always better to install fresh after backing up user data, then restore in new install. What do you mean by administer exactly?

Comment: Please stop using words like "dickhead" on askubuntu. We do not need that kind of attitude on AU. Anyone is free to downvote whatever they do not like. The system is capable enough to weed out serial downvoters by itself. "there is obviousley nothing wrong with my question" Well I do not agree with this statement since it has subjective statements. https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask is pretty clear about that.

Comment: @Rinzwind It's pretty clear...... is it running in gui mode totally if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Ubuntu like this? Can I give a Ubuntu computer to a employee who would rather die, than to have to touch a command line/shell, ever?

My mother (75 years old) uses Ubuntu and never touches command line. So yes, it is totally possible. You need to consider 2 use cases:

1. a user using the system.
2. an admin maintaining the system.

The 1st does not need the command line. If a user needs the command line he should ask the admin.

The 2nd should really be using the command line. In Windows if the desktop is broken you re-install. In Linux you use command line and fix the issue.

An admin needs to set the system up initially. Upgrading is NOT a task a USER should be doing; that is part of the admins tasks. An admin should install the LTS version so only needs to upgrade every 2 years (roughly) so the link you used is useless. You stick to 16.04, 18.04, 20.04 and skip in between releases.

Updates you can have the system do by itself but I would not myself; that too is an admin task and should be done periodically. Part of the task is to confirm what the update does before starting it. Another task is to provide updates for standalone software: I tend to install a browser from a download (I always install both firefox and chrome) so you can update the browser outside of the operating system.

Answer (score 3):

Terminal programs and GUI programs that serve the same purpose are intentionally designed to have partially overlapping functionality, but typically neither a terminal program nor its GUI counterpart can be used as a complete replacement for the other one. Terminal programs often have many more options than GUI programs which have similar functionality at a cost of being harder to understand and use. You need to run `man program-name` to show the terminal program's manual instead of accessing a GUI program's features simply and intuitively through the user interface.

In order to make the instructions compatible with both Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server, a lot of documentation webpages and other online resources provide the terminal commands only. Without accessing the terminal, you would be at a loss about how to make use of these resources.